# Как передавать в функцию объекты различных типов?

Tags: c, строки, функции, типы

Я хочу создать функцию, уменьшающую длину.

```
void my_realloc(... obj, size_t len) {
   obj = (typeof(obj)*) realloc(obj, sizeof(typeof(*obj)) * len);
}
```

И я хочу использовать её и как для строк, и как для массивов строк. То есть

```
char* st = (char*) malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // Длина строки 10
char** masStr = (char**) malloc(20 * sizeof(char*)); // Длина массива строк 20

my_realloc(st, 5); // Длина строки st стала 5
my_realloc(masStr, 14); // Длина массива строк masStr стала 14
```

Можно ли что-то подставить вместо ... ?

Можно ли вообще это как-то реализовать?

Comment: Начнем с того, что вы, похоже, компилируете как С++, а не как С — иначе вам приведения типов не потребовались бы. А в С можно использовать `void*`. Только вот `obj = realloc(obj...` — опасно, грозит утечкой памяти, если `realloc` вернет `NULL`.

Comment: а разве `realloc` может вернуть `NULL`, если я гарантированно буду передавать значение длины меньше или равной текущей?

я использую gcc

Comment: Мало ли — какая фрагментация памяти все испортит. Береженого, как говорится...

Comment: `#define my_realloc(x,l) (__typeof__(x))realloc((x), sizeof(*(x)) *(l))` -- так подойдет? (должно сработать даже в крестах)